# How to allow a user to upload files into my ec2 instance

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

**To the point**: My code below does not allow users to upload videos and images to the website, is there something wrong with the permissions I need to set, the variable `$filentmpname = $_FILES['videofile']['tmp_name'];` or is there something else I don't know of. Any links will be appreciated.

**Fluff and more clarification (Dont have to read this)**: I'm running an ubuntu ec2 instance and I had this code below on my website. (So the user can upload files: video and image for that video). However, it didn't work. (Some of you guys might ask "how so it didn't work?" and when I say it didn't work I mean that the files didn't get uploaded at all. Also there is an error on the file uploading page but it says this: **The message port closed before a response was received.** so I can't see the error). Anyone know why this isn't working? Is it because of the directories I need to fix and if so, where should I tell my program to save it? Is there something wrong with the variable  `$filentmpname = $_FILES['videofile']['tmp_name'];` (Please don't respond with "yeah your uploading it to the wrong directory or the variable is wrong, go fix it" and then dislike the post because I dont know how to fix it that's why I'm here) or are there some permissions I need to change?
Any links you can guys can provide will be appreciated.

**Simple code:**

```
$pnoyes = $_POST['private'];
    $music = $_POST['music'];

    $title = $_POST['title'];
     $description = $_POST['description'];
     $maint = $_POST['maint'];
     $subt = $_POST['subt'];
       $file = $_FILES['videofile'];

    $filename = $_FILES['videofile']['name'];
    $filentmpname = $_FILES['videofile']['tmp_name'];
    $filesize = $_FILES['videofile']['size'];
    $fileerror = $_FILES['videofile']['error'];
    $filentyp = $_FILES['videofile']['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $filename);
    $fileactualext = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowedFiles = array("mp4");  
       $imfile = $_FILES['videofile'];
    //echo $_FILES['videofile']['type'];

    $imfilename = $_FILES['thumbnail']['name'];
    $imfilentmpname = $_FILES['thumbnail']['tmp_name'];
    $imfilesize = $_FILES['thumbnail']['size'];
    $imfileerror = $_FILES['thumbnail']['error'];
    $imfilentyp = $_FILES['thumbnail']['type'];

    $imfileExt = explode('.', $imfilename);
    $imfileactualext = strtolower(end($imfileExt));

    $imallowedFiles = array("png", "jpg", "jpeg");  

    if(in_array($imfileactualext, $imallowedFiles) && in_array($fileactualext, $allowedFiles)) {
    //echo "yay";
        if($imfileerror == 0 && $fileerror == 0){
            if ($imfilesize < 5000000 && $filesize < 500000000) {
               $zero = 0;
                  $uservideoid = $_SESSION["userid"];
                echo $uservideoid;
                $fileid = uniqid('', true). "." .$fileactualext;
                $filedestination = 'videouploads/' . $fileid;
                move_uploaded_file($filentmpname, $filedestination);
                $sql = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO posts (user_id, video_id, video_likes, video_dislikes, video_views, title, description, maintag, subtag, private, time_uploaded, music) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
                $timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $sql->execute(array($uservideoid, $fileid, $zero, $zero, $zero, $title, $description, $maint, $subt, $pnoyes, $timestamp, $music));
                echo $fileid;
                echo "that succesful failed to fail!";



                $imfileid = uniqid('', true). "." .$imfileactualext;
                $imfiledestination = 'thumbnail_uploads/' . $imfileid;
                move_uploaded_file($imfilentmpname, $imfiledestination);
                $sql = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO thumbails (user_id, image_id, video_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
                $sql->execute(array($uservideoid, $imfileid, $fileid));
                echo $imfileid;
                echo "that succesful failed to fail!";



        }
        else{
            echo "file too big nerd";
        }
                }
    else{
        echo "there was some error, try again now, later, or smash your keyboard";
    }

 }
     else{
         echo "File types are incorrect!";
     }
```

Comment: cross check the directory name and set the permission * chmod -R 777 videouploads *

Comment: @developerCK Are there any draw backs with using this command?

Comment: for now, first check if it works. by this way you are providing the read write executable capability to any one for that directory. later on you can customise that